# Can't find Cron mail and cron jobs dont work

Tags: bash, 22.04, cron, postfix

I have 2 scripts in crontab -e:

```
0 0 */3 * * /bin/bash /home/user/scripts/3day-san-backup.sh >> /var/log/3day-san-backup.log2>&1

0 0 */1 * * /bin/bash /home/user/scripts/1day-pny-backup.sh >> /var/log/1day-pny-backup.log 2>&1
```

They dont work, so I check cron logs. Also, the custom log files I made are empty.

```
Jun 21 08:09:01 goofy-server CRON[55054]: (user) CMD (/bin/bash /home/user/scripts/1day-pny-backup.sh >> /var/log/1day-pny-backup.log 2>&1)
Jun 21 08:09:01 goofy-server CRON[55052]: (user) MAIL (mailed 74 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

So the mail doesn't work so I try to download something:

I ran `sudo apt-get install postfix`, then `cp /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.debian /etc/postfix/main.cf`, then I added `inet_interfaces = loopback-only` in the new file. I just want to setup the mail system locally so I can read the cron logs. But when I type `mail`, it just says `Cannot open mailbox /var/mail/user: No such file or directory.` I do have `/var/spool/mail` though, but that directory is empty. Though, when I check the cron logs again, I don't get that error that says something about the mail. Where is the mail, and why are my custom logs empty?

Comment: You need to change `/var/log/3day-san-backup.log2>&1` to `/var/log/3day-san-backup.log 2>&1` ... Does your user have write permissions to those log files? ... Are your scripts executable?

Comment: The log entry `... got status 0x004b from MTA#012` suggests there was already some type of mail transfer agent running before you installed postfix (otherwise you'd get `No MTA installed, discarding output` I think?)

Comment: `mail` program wants to use file `/var/mail/username` by default as mail storage, and it doesn't exist. If Postfix delivered mail correctly (check in `/var/log/mail.log`), then it may be configured to deliver mail to different location (probably `/home/username/Maildir`). Check parameters `home_mailbox` and `mail_spool_directory` in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file. The first one should be empty (or not present at all), and the second one should be `/var/mail` for mail delivery compatible with `mail` program.

Comment: @raj, I did not have either of those parameters in my  `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file, but I added the ``mail_spool_directory`` to it.

Comment: And does it work with `mail_spool_directory` added? (remember to restart Postfix after changing `main.cf`)